# Why is this binary to decimal conversion not working for even numbers?

Tags: python

New to python here, I tried this code:

```
binary = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] 
def bin_to_dec(binary):
    num = 0
    ini = 0
    sum1 = 0
    print()
    #print("Binary: ",binary)
    for i in binary[::-1]:        
        num = 2**(ini) * binary[-i]
        print("Binary -i: " , binary[-i])
        print("num: ", num)
        sum1 = sum1 + num
        print("i: ", i)
        print("ini: ", ini)
        print("Sum: " , sum1)
        print()
        ini = ini + 1
    print("Result in integer: ", sum1)
    return sum1
bin_to_dec(binary)
```

Like the question says it works for if the last item in the list is 1 but not if it is 0. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You're misdiagnosing the problem, probably because you get a few correct results by coincidence. The big problem is that `i` is an element in `binary`, but you're using it as an index - `binary[-i]`  is either `binary[-1]` or `binary[0]`, so you only look at the last and the first digit.

Comment: yes, that is where I made the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already iterating through `binary`, you should just use `i` instead of `binary[-1]` which is the key issue.

- `i` gives you the actual value for each index.

  - If you want the both the index and value, use `for idx, val for enumerate(binary)`.
  - If you just want the index, `for idx in range(len(binary))` works fine enough.
- `binary[-i]` will vary depending on which `0` or `1` you're on.

  - e.g. for the second index, `binary[-i]` will be `binary [-0]`, which is incorrect.

Fixed code:

```
binary = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] 
def bin_to_dec(binary):
    num = 0
    ini = 0
    sum1 = 0
    print()
    #print("Binary: ",binary)
    for i in binary[::-1]:        
        num = 2**(ini) * i
        print("i: " , i)
        print("num: ", num)
        sum1 = sum1 + num
        print("ini: ", ini)
        print("Sum: " , sum1)
        print()
        ini = ini + 1
    print("Result in integer: ", sum1)
    return sum1
bin_to_dec(binary)
```

Sample: https://ideone.com/edm8Rj

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a different approach, such as this one:

```
def bin_to_dec(binary):
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        num += binary[(-i-1)]*(2**i)
    return num
```

Answer (score 1):

You code multiplies the power of two by binary[-i] which you expect to be the iTh bit from the end but your i variable does not contain an index, it contains the bit at that position.  so the result will be formed by a combination of the first and last bit (indexes -0 and -1) instead of what you were expecting.

A simpler approach would be to move forward in the bits and multiply the previous result by 2 before adding each bit

```
num = 0
for bit in binary:
    num = num * 2 + bit
```